# Tool to display geo-spatial data from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, plugins, import, geoserver

I am currently searching for a tool such as GeoServer or QGIS to display geo-spatial data stored in MongoDB (MongoDB provides specific 2d-indices for that). In my case I am storing LineStrings.

The existing plugin for an integration of MongoDB sources in GeoServer is not supported and wasn't published in the name of GeoServer.

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/MongoDB-plugin-td5042018.html

My try led to the same problem of a missing layer.

For the combination of MongoDB and QGIS there is also a plugin that internally converts the MangoDB data in CSV and integrates it then in QGIS.

Is there any open-source software for visualizing geo-spatial data supporting the integration of data from MongoDB?

Any suggestions?

Best,

Tron

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a simple solution for the time being and it's available in the official QGIS plugin repo:
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis-mongodb-loader/

I also have a plugin that allows you to make edits and save those changes in MongoDB through QGIS, but I'm sure if I'm allowed to release the plugin as it is used internally by my company. I'll be working on redeveloping the plugin in my own time so I can release it through the QGIS plugin repo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but if you would build [MongoDB OGR Driver for GDAL Library](https://github.com/mongogis/mongodb-gdal-driver) yourself perhaps you can make QGIS use that.
Also, mapserver seems to support [OGR/GDAL](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/ogr.html) as input.

Otherwise, how about making a simple node.js app that displays the data on a leaflet map?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Haven't worked with OGR Driver for GDAL Library. In the worst case I need to implement a plugin for GeoServer access, but that could be time consuming. Since MongoDB provides geospatial support, I really thought there would be more interest in an interface between MongoDB and any common visualization tool such as GeoServer, Mapserver oder QGIS.

Comment: Check with the guys at Boundless. Looks like they teamed up with MongoDB for support in their OpenGeo Suite http://boundlessgeo.com/press-release/boundless-partners-mongodb-inc/. And from OpenGeo Suite 4.1 there seems to be support for MongoDB http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/introduction/extensions.html#intro-extensions-mongodb

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look at both sources. But sadly, only the basic version is open-source for a certain time frame.

Answer (score 0):

It is honestly really surprising, that there is currently no possibility to use any common FULL open-source tool for the visualization of MongoDB's geo data.

There are some discussions about using QGIS for that, but the link to the mentioned plugin is dead:

http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed (mentioned here: http://geokoder.com/mongodb-plugin-for-quantum-gis ) The hint, that a team is working on that (without any schedule) is not helpful.

In my eyes that is a big weak point for MongoDB when working with geo data.

Answer (score 0):

you can install geoserver from [opengeo package](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/introduction/extensions.html#intro-extensions-mongodb) (comes with the mongodb connector).
when publishing a layer from mongodb on geoserver - you can visualize it through the geoserver "[layer preview](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/layerpreview/index.html)" over openlayers.