# How to integrate Geoserver into an application to serve points as layers

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, geoserver

I am currently developing an application and it has a map portion where we have to load more than 10,000 points on a map. We are using Google Map Javascript API to display all these points as markers. What we have experienced is that it takes almost forever to get all of those points on the map and then again it mighty load on our server so most times we get a time-out.

We have thought of using Geoserver. Our approach is to connect/get a Geoserver plugin for MongoDB (that what we use in storing all the points) and then specify our data-source on Geoserver so that it can create a WMS layer for all the points we intend to load/display on a map.

What we have not figured out is how to Integrate Geoserver into our current solution

We have searched for possible implementations of a similar solution but found nothing that tells on how to integrate Geoserver into an application.

Please help if you do have a idea. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to be more clear on what you need help with. It seems like the majority of the challenge lies with the source data, the points. You mention mongo as the geoserver store, but don't mention where the points live today.

Comment: @JasonKoopmans - The points are still on MongoDB. What we have an issue with is how to integrate Geoserver into our application programmatically.

Comment: What part of your application?  Loading the data into geoserver/mongo or presenting the map as a wms layer?

Comment: @JasonKoopmans - Both

Comment: :For the front end, leftlet.js works great.  I've heard others do good things with other libraries (OpenLayers) but I've got firsthand experiences with leaflet.js.  

On the Mongo side, I don't have a lot of advice to offer.  I'm guessing this choice is driven from Mongo being the source of the point data?  

This SO thread could help a little:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527878/tool-to-display-geo-spatial-data-from-mongodb

Comment: Have you installed and configured the Mongo plugin?  You can preview the data in the layer preview tool in GeoServer.  Have you been able to publish a layer through that plugin?